# Cannot find spree user_registation views

Tags: spree, spree-auth-devise

I cannot use the spree user registration views anywhere. Am using spree 2.3.2 with the spree_fancy and spree_auth_devise gems. I would have thought that they would be in the spree_auth_devise gems but they aren't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using the views from the spree_auth_devise branch for spree 2.2. Copied them and placed them in my views directory. Everything working as it should.